# Как получить последовательность пар?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
int[] B = new int[6] {  111, 22, 33, 43,54,66 };
var w = B.GroupBy(x => x % 10);
```

Как продолжить мой запрос, чтобы получить пары ключ-сумма элементов с этим ключом?

Comment: не очень понятно, что вы хотите получить. Что должно быть ключом и о какой сумме идет речь?

Comment: В приведённом выше запросе ключом будет последняя цифра числа. Для каждого этого ключа я хочу сформировать пару, в которую войдёт этот ключ и сумма элементов, сгруппированных по этому ключу.

Comment: с первым понятно. Теперь поясните пожалуйста, что такое "сумма элементов, сгруппированных по этому ключ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            int[] B = new int[6] { 111, 22, 33, 43, 54, 66 };

            var w = B.GroupBy(x => x % 10).Select(x => new
            { 
                key = x.Key,
                sum = x.Sum()
            });

            foreach (var g in w)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key {0} sum {1}", g.key, g.sum);

            }
```